# Calling a method to Objective-C from a C++ file

Tags: objective-c, objective-c++

I am calling a method inside `BLEObject.m` from the `UnityBridge.mm` file.

`BLEObject.m` has

```
- (void) SendSetting:(NSData*)data forSelected:(NSString*)type with:(NSData*)clublength and:(NSData*)clubloft{
}
```

`UnityBridge.mm` has

```
void bleplugin_sendSetting(unsigned char data, char* type, float clublength, float clubloft)
{
   BLEObject *bleobj = [[BLEObject alloc] init];
    //NSString* objcstring = @(type);
    NSString* string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:type];
    NSData *data_ = [NSData dataWithBytes: &data length: sizeof(data)];
    NSData *clublength_ = [NSData dataWithBytes: &clublength length: sizeof(clublength)];
    NSData *clubloft_ = [NSData dataWithBytes: &clubloft length: sizeof(clubloft)];
    [bleobj SendSetting:data_ forSelected:string with:clublength_ and:clubloft_];
    return;
}
```

I have an error at;

`[bleobj SendSetting:data_ forSelected:string with:clublength_ and:clubloft_];` with the expected expression as shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: Please, add the header file.

Comment: and is not accepted. I changed to and_together_with. - (void) SendSetting:(NSData*)data forSelected:(NSString*)type with:(NSData*)clublength and_together_with:(NSData*)clubloft;

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

`and` is a keyword in C++; it is syntactically the same as if you wrote `&&`. (And similarly, `or` for `||`, `not` for `!`, `not_eq` for `!=`, `bitand` for `&`, `bitor` for `|`, `xor` for `^`, `compl` for `~`, `and_eq` for `&=`, `or_eq` for `|=`, and `xor_eq` for `^=`).

So you should avoid any identifiers with such names when you are using C++.